# Ember-cli project and web workers

Tags: ember.js, web-worker, ember-cli

*Ember-cli: 0.33*

**How can I use web workers within an ember-cli based project?**

Example - I have a component and I want to start a web worker:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  _startWorker: function() {
    var worker = new Worker('path/to/worker.js');
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

In which folder should I put the worker.js file inside the ember-cli project structure?
Which other changes are required (Brocfile.js,...)?

Comment: Relevant issue: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/1011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

1) In your ember project root folder add a new folder with the name 'workers'.

2) Update your Brocfile.js (see Screenshot)

3) Write workers :-)

[image: Needed changes for webworkers support]

Comment: @torazaburo You will need to manually transpile the files when taking this approach. This can be done with an in repo addon. For an example of a project doing something similar with service workers, checkout: https://github.com/DockYard/ember-service-worker/blob/master/lib/service-worker-builder.js

Answer (score 2):

relevant code from @Steven's solution for easy copying:

```js
/* global require, module, process */

var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
var pickFiles = require('broccoli-static-compiler');

var app = new EmberApp();

var workers = pickFiles('workers', {
  srcDir: '/',
  files: ['*.js'],
  destDir: '/assets/workers'
});

if (process.env.EMBER_ENV === 'production') {
  workers = require('broccoli-uglify-js')(workers, {
    mangle: true,
    compress: true
  });
}

module.exports = app.toTree(workers);
```

Answer (score 0):

If that helps someone, I managed to start using using workers with the config below, using ember-cli >= 2.4.2 to be able to use `outputFile`:

```
//ember-cli-build.js
..
//don't prepend CDN to worker paths (or CORS issue)
fingerprint: {
  exclude: ['worker'],
  ..
}
..
var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  ..
  app.import('vendor/localforage.js');//use localforage outside of workers
  app.import('vendor/localforage.js',outputFile:'assets/workers/localforage.js'});//use localforage inside of workers
  app.import('vendor/worker_localforage.js',outputFile:'assets/workers/worker_localforage.js'});
  app.import('vendor/worker_test_indexeddb.js',outputFile:'assets/workers/worker_test_indexeddb.js'});
});
```

Then the workers code:

```
//vendor/worker_localforage.js
importScripts('localforage.js');

self.onmessage = function(e) {
  var namespace=e.data.namespace;
  var msg=e.data.msg;
  var data=e.data.data;
  //console.log("msg to worker",namespace,msg);
  if (msg==="load") {
    localforage.getItem(namespace).then(function(res){
      self.postMessage({msg:"load",data:res});
    });
  }
  else if (msg==="persist") {
    localforage.setItem(namespace,data).then(function(res){
      self.postMessage({msg:"persist",data:res});
    });
  }
};
```

Calling the workers from anywhere in your app:

```
self.worker=new Worker("assets/workers/worker_localforage.js");
var worker=self.worker;
prom2= new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve,reject){
  worker.onmessage=function(e){
    if (e.data.msg==="load") {
      resolve(e.data.data);
    }
  }
});
worker.postMessage({namespace:self.adapterNamespace(),msg:"load"});
```

Comment: this is a good idea, but unfortunately ember-cli@2.11.1 does not transpile the worker files. This is probably expected and presumably impacts other versions of ember-cli.